# Android decodeByteArray very slow on own Thread but not on UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am actually working on a camera based project. I am adding in a queue, preview frames from **onPreviewFrame** from the camera that I get back in a running thread to process and draw it in a SurfaceView. (My goal is to send it over network).

My problem is that the BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray() function is very slow on my custom thread, but works really fine on the **UI Thread**:

**this works fine:**

```
    private void drawFromThread(final byte[] data) {

    size = mCamera.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage yuvimage;
    yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width,size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 10,baos);  
    final byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap bmp;
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
            Canvas canvas = contactView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
            contactView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    });
}
```

**But this, is really slow:**

```
    private void drawFromThread(final byte[] data) {

    size = mCamera.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage yuvimage;
    yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width,
            size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 10,
            baos);
    final byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
    Bitmap bmp;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
    Canvas canvas = contactView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
    contactView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

I googled a lot but didn't find anyone with the same problem.

I know there are most efficient way to use the camera and a SurfaceView, i have another surfaceView that is used to display my camera frames in the "standard way". But i am trying to simulate frames that i would get from network and drawing it on a SurfaceView.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem was coming from. I was pushing in a queue my camera preview frames from the Ui Thread. Frames that i was retrieving from the queue on another thread. The problem was that the Ui Thread was pushing more frames per seconds in the queue than the other thread could handle per second. Doing the decodeByteArray on the Ui Thread, was slowing it down, which could let time to the other thread to draw my bitmap.
I changed the kind of queue that i am using to make it faster and still try to find a way to render faster in my thread.
If someone has advice, i will take it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is appearing slow because you aren't actually doing anything on the UI thread in the slow example.  Chances are the canvas is being updated later because of something else running an update.  If instead you do the calculation in one thread and then render it in the UI it should have faster response times.

```
private void drawFromThread(final byte[] data) {

    size = mCamera.getPreviewSize();
    YuvImage yuvimage;
    yuvimage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width,size.height, null);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height), 10,baos);  
    final byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();

    final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
    ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas canvas = contactView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);
            contactView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    });
}
```

Notice the "expensive" decodeByteArray is done off the UI thread, but rendering is done ON the UI thread.  Does that not work?

Comment: Doing that, the problem is still the same. When i put the "expensive" decodeByteArray off the Ui Thread, it is really slow, but once I put it on the Ui Thread part, everything works perfectly. I have another SurfaceView that shows in real time my camera, when i use decodeByteArray in the Ui Thread part, i can see that both surface view are almost synchronized, but once i put just the decodeByteArray part off the Ui Thread, i can see a lag of 3 seconds.

Comment: What do you see lag?  The time it takes from when `final Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);` is executed and to when it is rendered?  Have you tried timing both executions, I am sure the are identical.

Comment: That is, I would imagine the time it takes to execute every single line of code is equivalent, the difference being when the `decodeByteArray` is done on the UI thread it renders immediately (since it's on the UI thread)

Comment: I just ran some test, the difference between both is of 0.020 seconds slower in the thread. But not enough to create the lag. It must be because it renders immediately on the UiThread as you said. So what would you suggest to me to make it faster ? Would it be a wrong thing to process it directly on the Ui Thread knowing that I would have to render it 24 times per seconds ?

Comment: Well, let's say you run it 24 times in 24 threads.  It may render out of order just because of non-determinism.  If you need them to execute in order, I would have a single-threaded executor run them all and push to the UI thread each.  In that case, since the UI thread too is single threaded, it should be as responsive as possible while in order.

Comment: Okay, i didn't precise it, but every frames are rendered on only one Thread. my method drawFromThread is called from a main loop, getting frames out from a queue. Having a thread per frames would be crazy. I was wondering so how i could make the render off the UI Thread more efficient.

Comment: I guess at this point it's too hard to tell.  When do you see the delay?  If you were to time each major operation, how long does each take?  For instance on my example, the major pieces would be 1. start of method to compressToJpeg, 2. compressToJpeg to decodeByteArray 3. decodeByteArray to runOnUiThread and 4.  runOnUiThread to unlockCanvasAndPost.  Not sure if it's easy to grab these numbers.